# Signal conditioning circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, pcb-design, signal, signal-conditioning

I want to design a signal conditioning circuit using an op-amp.

It will be used to interface with the ADC input of an Arduino Nano.

The maximum voltage to be measured is 250 Vrms, 50 Hz, and it should use a 5A Hall current sensor ([ACS712](https://www.allegromicro.com/-/media/files/datasheets/acs712-datasheet.pdf)-5A)

I don't know where to start.

Comment: Use an AD8479 for example for measuring voltage ..., other means could be used.

Comment: What exactly do you want to measure? With the ACS712 I assume you're measuring current--what's the highest current you'll need to measure? How do you want to condition the signal--just adjust to the right voltage range, or do you want to filter it too?

Comment: The maximum current I need to measure is 1 A.

I want to condition the signal to a suitable voltage range.

Answer (score 0):

I made this circuit according to the requirements. There is also a simpler way of doing conditioning. However, I preferred this one here. It would be better to substitute Rf with a trimmer .
Greetings.

[image]